# JoptionPane.showInputDialog Without cancel button and exit handle

Tags: java, joptionpane

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrdTN.jpg

I wanna get this kind of Input Dialog The issue is that it only accept int type 
found this
    `

```
 String[] options = {"OK"};

int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "The Title", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options , options[0]);
```

`
I'd like also to handle the X(quit button the red button Close Button) because it causes an Exception
errors caused

i'm using a regex.Matcher

```
at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks

Comment: *what* have you tried to solve your problem? we won't code for you..

Comment: Check out the [JOptionPane API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) as it will tell you how to do this.

Comment: Explain this: *I'd like also to handle the X(quit button) because it causes an Exception* . Also what is the error message and code that you have tried. Then we can help. Also read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: just modified the Question Waiting for help

Answer (score 1):

### Existing solution

You could use the InputDialog of JOptionPane

```
String res = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your name", "The title", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
System.err.println(res);
```

*Be aware of that result is **NULL** if the user closed the dialog or hasn't inserted some text.*

But this solution isn't **exactly** looking like the dialog which you want to have. You will have to create your own JOptionPane.

---

### Own solution

I would recommend to use a modal JDialog and remove the frame (that causes problems for you) with

> .setUndecorated(true)

or override dispose() in your own class to handle it

```
@Override
public void dispose()
{
    //YOUR CODE
    super.dispose();
}
```

The begin of your own class could look like this:

```
public class MyOptionPane extends JDialog
{
    public MyOptionPane(Dialog owner, boolean modal)
    {
        super(owner, modal);
        this.setUndecorated(true); //Remove the frame
    }
}
```

Go on with these steps:

1. Add Label "Enter your name" to GUI
2. Add Textfield to GUI
3. Add OK button to GUI (With ActionListener)
4. Attach ActionListener at "OK" button
5. Fetch textfield value on "OK" click, return it and dispose your JDialog

Comment this post if you have questions or remarks.